# Map values on Google map android

Tags: android, android-layout

If there are values for Longitude and latitude how to map these values on GoogleMaps.Please give me links to this..

```
     Ex: Longitude:12.93434334   Latitude:144.12121212
```

How to map these values on google map and get the position

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to set/display map at particular coordinates you need to get [MapController](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html) from [MapView](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getController%28%29) and set/animate to center you wish.

```
MapView view = (MapView)findViewById(id);
MapController controller = view.getController();

GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

controller.setCenter(gp);
// controller.animateTo(gp); alternatively...
```